# how can I select all elements between two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select all elements between two given elements. I have html like this...

```
<h2>This is firsty</h2>
<p>Some para</p>
<ul>
  <li>list items</li>
  <li>list items</li>
  <li>list items</li>
  <li>list items</li>
  <li>list items</li>
</ul>
<h2>Secondy</h2>
<p>More text</p>
```

I want to select everything from the first `h2` to the second `h2`, so I can wrap it in a `div`, ending up with all sections in their own wrapper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var elems = $('h2:first').nextUntil('h2');
```

Or, to perform the actual wrapping:

```
$('h2:first').nextUntil('h2').wrapAll('<div />');
```

More generically:

```
$('h2').each(
    function(i,e) {
        $(this)
            .nextUntil(this.tagName)
            .wrapAll('<div />');
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dahD4/1/).

In order to include the starting element simply use `andSelf()` as part of the selector chain:

```
$('h2:first').nextUntil('h2').andSelf().wrapAll('<div />');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dahD4/).

---

**Update for jQuery v3+**
`andSelf()` was removed in v3 and should be replaced with `addBack()`:

```
$('h2:first').nextUntil('h2').addBack().wrapAll('<div />');
```

References:

- [`andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/).
- [`nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/).
- [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/).

Comment: That is great. Is there any way to include the `h2` in the section before wrapping?

Comment: Actually got it: `$el = $("h2").eq(0); $el.nextUntil("h2").add($el)`

Comment: How would this be done with commonjs

Comment: Note that `andSelf` is deprecated and was removed in v3 and should be replaced with `addBack` in newer jQuery versions (v1.8+)